# How can I see which IP address Google Cloud Function instance use?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to see the IP address of my google function instance. I've tried to look request object's headers but couldn't find anything useful. Is there any way to find it?

I am using python SDK but I don't think this is language dependent.

Comment: Short answer is no. But to correctly provide a solution, my question is WHY do you need an IP? and which IP? the Inbound IP (originated from outside) or the outbound IP (originated from the Cloud Function to call an API)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I was interested in outbound IP address. I wanted to test when I make a call to third party API, all instances use the same IP or not. I guess John's answer explains why all instances gets blocked when single instance exceeds quota limit of that third party API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloud Functions do not have a public IP address assigned to the function.

Cloud Function egress traffic is routed to a proxy which then forwards the traffic to the public Internet. The only method to determine the current public IP address is to call a public endpoint which returns the public IP address of the frontend to Cloud Functions.

Here is an example endpoint: https://api64.ipify.org/?format=json

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a outbound static IP with Cloud Functions, you can achieve this [by configuration](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings). 3 important steps

- Create a [serverless VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) and [plug it to your Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc)
- Set the [egress param to "ALL"](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#egress_settings) to route ALL (private and public IPs) the request from the Cloud Functions
- Configure a Cloud NAT and reserve IP(s) to use when you perform an external call. And you can use the John's answer to check if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Just if someone needs this.

After doing the steps described by guillaume and exploring the link that also John suggested, I was able to get my cloud function's IP with the following python code:

```py
from requests import get

ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print(f'My public IP address is: {ip}')
```

In my case, I was looking to see if my cloud function had the same IP address as my NAT gateway since I need to put the IP in a whitelist and this helped me a lot!